# Aligning image and div across screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design my first website and I'm having trouble aligning my top bar css to align with my logo, I have a feeling i am doing this incorrectly because depending on the user's screen size it will also look different with a fixed height css value.

This is what i want it to look like on all screen resoloutions:
[image]

this is what it looks like on a lower screen res:

[image]

below is my markup:

```css
h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0 0 72px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: #685206;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #EEB84F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.thumbwrapper {
  width: auto;
}

.thumb {
  background: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 121px;
  height: 174px;
}

.img {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 121px;
  height: 174px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.img:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #666688;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background: #333;
}

.right {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/static/logo2.png" width="100%" /></div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <h1>Latest Additions</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbwrapper">
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AntiMatter_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DianaOurMotherHerLifeandLegacy_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ThePersianConnection_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/BloodHunt_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/UFConFoxWeidmanvsGastelum_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheOttomanLieutenant_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wildflower_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/NoWaytoLive_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/CopandaHalfNewRecruit_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheHorseDancer_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/KillingGround_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DanceAcademyTheMovie_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Hypersomnia_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/LostVegasHiway_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wildflower_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/KissandCry_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ForgottenEvil_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheMidwife_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AwakentheShadowman_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ShotCaller_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ViceroysHouse_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/StoryOfAGirl_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/JasperJones_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AKindAffair_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/LegoDCSuperHeroGirlsBrainDrain_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DiaryofaWimpyKidTheLongHaul_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheChristmasCure_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wakefield_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ADeadlyAffair_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/FatalDefense_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheArtofUs_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/FirstKill_2017.png" class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can view it live at [this online location](http://moviept.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `logo` image, will shrink when you go on smaller screens. Because the image must fit inside that `10%` width you set on the `.left` div.

Now, i am not going to change your entire structure but i suggest you set a height of `50px` to the `.logo` ( the div around the image ) and a `background-color: #EEB84F` . This is because the `topbar` has these styles set.

Then you can center the `logo` img by using display:flex on `logo`

see Snippet below or fiddle > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytm9zz4h/1/)

```css
.logo  {
  min-height:50px;
  background:#EEB84F;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0 0 72px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: #685206;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #EEB84F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.thumbwrapper {
  width: auto;
}

.thumb {
  background: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 121px;
  height: 174px;
}

.img {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 121px;
  height: 174px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.img:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #666688;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background: #333;
}

.right {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/static/logo2.png" width="100%" /></div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <h1>Latest Additions</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbwrapper">
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AntiMatter_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DianaOurMotherHerLifeandLegacy_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ThePersianConnection_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/BloodHunt_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/UFConFoxWeidmanvsGastelum_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheOttomanLieutenant_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wildflower_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/NoWaytoLive_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/CopandaHalfNewRecruit_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheHorseDancer_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/KillingGround_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DanceAcademyTheMovie_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Hypersomnia_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/LostVegasHiway_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wildflower_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/KissandCry_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ForgottenEvil_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheMidwife_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AwakentheShadowman_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ShotCaller_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ViceroysHouse_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/StoryOfAGirl_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/JasperJones_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AKindAffair_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/LegoDCSuperHeroGirlsBrainDrain_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DiaryofaWimpyKidTheLongHaul_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheChristmasCure_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wakefield_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ADeadlyAffair_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/FatalDefense_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheArtofUs_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/FirstKill_2017.png" class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a suggestion, you should put `.topbar` outside the `left` and `right` div . and put the logo inside it.

Your structure should be something like

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/static/logo2.png" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

also not sure why you need that `left` div, you can easily make that `gray` section without a new div ( border or pseudo-elements etc. )

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logo to be always on top without overlap, you can set a specific height for that logo image to about `height: 50px`. Otherwise, use media query to set its height specifically for lower resolutions.

Comment: if you set height:50px for the logo image , you must set `width:auto` so the image will have same aspect ration as original. So the width of the logo will exceed the width of the space available, and thus going out of it's container

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the height of `.logo` same as the height of `.topbar + padding`. Then using `transform` align image in center of `.logo`, you might need to use media query at certain screen resolution, if needed.

```css
h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0 0 72px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: #685206;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #EEB84F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EEB84F;
}

.logo > img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.thumbwrapper {
  width: auto;
}

.thumb {
  background: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 121px;
  height: 174px;
}

.img {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 121px;
  height: 174px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.img:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #666688;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background: #333;
}

.right {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/static/logo2.png" width="100%" /></div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <h1>Latest Additions</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbwrapper">
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AntiMatter_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DianaOurMotherHerLifeandLegacy_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ThePersianConnection_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/BloodHunt_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/UFConFoxWeidmanvsGastelum_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheOttomanLieutenant_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wildflower_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/NoWaytoLive_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/CopandaHalfNewRecruit_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheHorseDancer_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/KillingGround_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DanceAcademyTheMovie_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Hypersomnia_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/LostVegasHiway_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wildflower_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/KissandCry_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ForgottenEvil_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheMidwife_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AwakentheShadowman_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ShotCaller_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ViceroysHouse_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/StoryOfAGirl_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/JasperJones_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/AKindAffair_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/LegoDCSuperHeroGirlsBrainDrain_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/DiaryofaWimpyKidTheLongHaul_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheChristmasCure_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/Wakefield_2016.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/ADeadlyAffair_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/FatalDefense_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/TheArtofUs_2017.png" class="img"></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://d2tsz823kvlf97.cloudfront.net/FirstKill_2017.png" class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```